# jquery keep on redirecting om countdown

Tags: jquery, countdown

this is my jquery countdown code when click event is trigger on id dlbtn

```
var settimmer = 0;
$(function() {
    $('#dlbtn').click(function() {
        $('#dlnotify').toggle('slow');
        window.setInterval(function() {
            var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
            var updateTime = eval(timeCounter) - eval(1);
            $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);
            if (updateTime <= 0) {
                window.location = ('/dl.php?fid=12');

                $('#dlnotify').hide();
            }
        }, 500);
        updateTime--;
        return false; //Kill the Event after request
    });

});​
```

my script keep on hitting dl.ph page

Comment: it redirects because updateTime < 0.  Can you please post the html.

Comment: sure heres the link http://www.game143.com/f/skfh4fcfb24ac018a/365-board-games/ i use ==0 but it show minus value

Comment: It counted down and then redirected to the download page. What is the problem.

Comment: when i use crome i found that It keep on requesting dl.php nd crome notify me that action is request multiple file
i use return false so the event will kill after request but no sence of using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the issue is however in order to remove the `setInterval` you need to make a call to `clearInterval`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Try this code:

```
var settimmer = 0;
$(function() {
    $('#dlbtn').click(function() {
        $('#dlnotify').toggle('slow');
        settimmer =window.setInterval(function() {
            var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
            var updateTime = eval(timeCounter) - eval(1);
            $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);
            if (updateTime <= 0) {

                window.location = ('/dl.php?fid=12');
                clearInterval(settimmer); // clear the interval to avoid multiple redirects 
                $('#dlnotify').hide();
            }
        }, 500);
        updateTime--;
        return false; //Kill the Event after request
    });

});​
```